# Is it possible to use Nox or Bluestacks with wsl2?

Tags: bluestacks, wsl2

Is it possible to use Nox or Bluestacks with wsl2 running on pc? Or any other android emulator for gaming? Windows 10 (not pro)

I tried https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041390952-How-to-run-BlueStacks-with-Hyper-V-enabled with no success

Comment: When you tried the Hyper-V version you linked, what errors did you face? It works for me when I use it.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me, too (Windows 10 Home). My CPU (Intel HD Graphics 4000) don't support Virtualization Technology, but still working.

Solution A:

1. I disabled Windows-Hypervisor Platform && activated WSL2
2. Disabled DMA kernel protection
3. PowerShell run:

   `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto`
4. After rebooting I installed BlueStacks Hyper-V (BETA)
   (version 4.240.15.4204)
   Link:
   https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360049701852-Release-Notes-for-BlueStacks-Hyper-V-BETA-

In installation progress of Bluestacks Hyper-V beta gave permission to current user for Hyper-V.

---

Solution B:
Alternatively, if it won't nothing work you can turn hypervisorlaunchtype off / auto (I did this before the Hyper-V version of bluestacks):

1. Download both files:
   https://filehorst.de/download.php?file=dbjlfnst
   https://filehorst.de/download.php?file=dfGhyFfA
2. Make a shortcut of each file
3. Go to preferences of each shortcut and add to path: `powershell -f "YOUR_PATH_TO_FILE"` for example: `powershell -f C:\Users\username\Desktop\runWSL2.ps1`
4. Now if you want to use WSL2 run "runWSL2.ps1" shortcut, after rebooting you can use it. Same for "runBluestacks.ps1", after rebooting you are able to use Bluestacks.

I know it's not the best solution, but before Hyper-V Beta I worked with this solution without any problems.

The short code of the power shell scripts are:

```
Write-Output "Turn on hypervisorlaunchtype for using WSL2 after Reboot"
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
Write-Output "Need to restart, please wait or confirm"
timeout 15
Restart-Computer
```

and

```
Write-Output "Turn off hypervisorlaunchtype for using WSL2 after Reboot"
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
Write-Output "Need to restart, please wait or confirm"
timeout 15
Restart-Computer
```